# How to dynamic load fontawesome icon by iconName and prefix?

Tags: angular, font-awesome-5, angular-fontawesome

I investigated the problem for dynamic load of fontawesome icon by iconName. But the code is not working. What is the reason? What is the best practice? And why I need the call for ngOnChanges() in the directive ngOnInit() hook? The error I get in the browser is "FontAwesome: Could not find icon. It looks like you've provided a null or undefined icon object to this component."

```js
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { library, dom } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fas,faCheck, faCalendar, faTimes } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IconDirective } from './icon.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, IconDirective],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FontAwesomeModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [FaIconComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    library.add(fas,faCheck, faCalendar, faTimes);
    dom.watch();
  }
}
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: '<div iconDirective></div>'
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() { }
}
```

```js
import { Directive, OnInit, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver }
from '@angular/core';
import { FaIconComponent } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { faCheck, faCalendar, faTimes } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { icon } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[iconDirective]'
})
export class IconDirective{
   constructor(      
      public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
      private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
      const componentFactory =
          this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(FaIconComponent);
      const componentRef =
          this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
      (<FaIconComponent>componentRef.instance).icon =
           icon({iconName: 'times', prefix: 'fas'});
      // (<FaIconComponent>componentRef.instance).iconProp = faCheck; //works
      (<FaIconComponent>componentRef.instance).ngOnChanges({});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the 0.5.0 release `angular-fontawesome` has a better support for rendering icon component dynamically. Check out the [official documentation](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/usage/features.md#programmatic-api):

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'fa-host',
  template: '<ng-container #host></ng-container>'
})
class HostComponent {
  @ViewChild('host', {static: true, read: ViewContainerRef}) container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }

  createIcon() {
    const factory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(FaIconComponent);
    const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
    componentRef.instance.icon = faUser;
    // Note that FaIconComponent.render() should be called to update the
    // rendered SVG after setting/updating component inputs.
    componentRef.instance.render();
  }
}
```

> What is the reason? The error I get in the browser is "FontAwesome: Could not find icon. It looks like you've provided a null or undefined icon object to this component."

Because you should have set `iconProp` input property, not `icon` property, which was errornously exposed on the component. Note that this is no longer the case in >0.5.0 (see example above).

> What is the best practice?

See example above.

> And why I need the call for ngOnChanges() in the directive ngOnInit() hook?

Because icon rendering is triggered by a call to [`ngOnChanges` hook](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges), which is performed by the Angular framework when you add component in the template. When creating a component dynamically Angular does not call this hook, so you need to do it manually. Note that in >0.5.0 there is a dedicated method, which triggers rendering without relying on this implementation detail - `FaIconComponent.render()`.